# Images not loading in MS Edge only

Tags: image, rendering, microsoft-edge

Images are not loading in Microsoft Edge but do load correctly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer.  Specifically, the only images that do not load are graphics hosted by the domain my computer is joined even though the images are fully qualified (ex. images are hosted at https://www.auburn.edu/...jpg and my computer is joined to the auburn.edu domain)

Using Edge's console I get the following error for each graphic: **SEC 7117 - This internet explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer.**

Suspecting it was a cross-domain issue, I opened the directory of images on the host to *.  (< IfModule mod_headers.c> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" < /IfModule>)

I know the correct solutions is "don't use Edge" but I cannot control that one.

Any changes I should make to the hosting server infrastructure or the HTML code?  I can't force updates to the Edge browser itself although it is set to factory defaults.

**(11/5 @ 4pm) Update: Even more odd, this issue only occurs while on the auburn network.**

Comment: Can you show the relevant piece of code having that problem?

Comment: @Alejandro - I could give you several examples but here's one - <img id="au-logo-ver" src="auburn.edu/images/oit/AUwordmark.png" alt="Auburn University logo" role="presentation">. Edge allows me to access the image directly in the browser but not if it's embeded in another site.

Comment: Try to add that domain to trusted site setting and again try to test the issue. Let us know about your testing result. You can also try to move the internal site to a non-local address space. so that Edge detects the site as public network. Alternatively you could move the resources to a true public address. You can also try to disable the Enhanced Protected mode to check whether it solves the issue or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - Added to the trusted sites and the problem still occurs.  I don't think it's a browser setting because if I'm not on our network, it works fine.  If I remove my computer from our domain and still access it on our network, it works fine.

Comment: UPDATE: Adding the website calling the images into the Trusted Sites does resolve the issue but that's not a good fix.  I added images to another site and it's blocked too until I add that site to Trusted Sites.  This solution doesn't scale.

Comment: At present, I am available with only this solution. I can see that you need better solution than this. I will try to find any other solution and if I find any than I will try to inform you.

Answer (score 0):

Ebay Images Not Displaying in Edge, Windows 10
The Fix – In Edge Browser open settings, select Privacy, Search, and Services – Under Clear Browsing Date Now select Choose what to clear – check - browsing history, download history, cookies and other site data, cached images then click the tab “clear now”.
Goto edge browser, open ebay and start surfing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer compatibility: I changed the settings to allow Internet Explorer to open compatable sites instead of Edge. Now photos are opening. I dont know enough about computers to know why, but it works for now.